# Cloud Functions overview chart showing a constant flow of errors while errors tab and logs don't show any errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I believe the screenshot is quite self-explanatory. Is there some other place I could look for those errors or is it possible that in reality there are no errors?

[image]

### Edit 2021-10-08

- It's a Python 3.7 function
- Function always returns a status of 200 or 204 (for options) unless the function itself crashed
- Logs show one log with a severity of "Warning" or higher in the past 7 days.

This is the function:

```
def main(request):

    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)

    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }

    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = {
            "ua": request.headers.get('User-Agent'),
            "ip": "n/a",
            "q": request.query_string.decode("utf-8")
        }
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {
            "ua": request.headers.get('User-Agent'),
            "ip": "n/a",
            "q": request.data.decode("utf-8")
        }
    
    if request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for') and len(request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for')) > 1:
        data['ip'] = request.access_route[0]

    print(data)

    return ('ok', 200, headers)
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the "errors" we are discussing here are "logical" errors returned from the body of your Cloud Function?  Remember, a Cloud Function is a REST call made by a client.  A return code of 200 means "OK" while a return code of "not" 200 may be taken as  an error.  This might be what is shown as errors/not errors in invocations.   The "Errors" at the bottom left may be considered "crashes" or other internal failures of Cloud Functions separate from what your logic decides to return.

Comment: While the screenshot may show what you observe, it's not useful for figuring out what is going on. We have no information about the type of function, how it is used, where it's being called from, what languages it uses, what a client invoking the function sees and so on. Please provide further information. It could be as simple as whether invocations of a HTTP Request Function return `HTTP 200 OK` or not.

Comment: Can you provide the logging from the `LOGS` tab? Should should show errors and statuses.

Comment: I've tried reproducing this issue with the function you provided but I wasn't able to get any error reporting in monitoring even after thousands of calls. I also tried returning `HTTP 204` to check if that would report as an error but it didn't. Are there any other steps besides using the function you provided to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Thanks @LluísMuñoz - these are the exact steps I'm doing and still getting the errors. This function gets ~2M invocations a day. No errors are to be seen in any of the logs, just on that one chart.

Comment: @SilverRingvee I think it would be best to report this issue on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187203&template=0) for the GCP team to look into this.

Comment: @FaridShumbar did that. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

As @JosephLust mentioned, check the `LOGS` tab for errors and statuses.

You can also use [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting) for your Cloud Functions to view errors in the [GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/errors?_ga=2.137608624.1617491186.1633525078-163333918.1612439028&_gac=1.179979734.1632481757.CjwKCAjw7rWKBhAtEiwAJ3CWLECUWkAQCoG5RL9LND17h9S_lPCOz9wPEJgkZU8GmZlRrFAwAE-bZBoCg68QAvD_BwE).

Going back to the @Kolban's comment, the "errors" you are receiving in this case can be "logical" errors returned from the body of your Cloud Function. A Cloud Function is a REST call made by a client. A return code of `200` means "OK" while a return code of "not" `200` may be taken as an error. This might be what is shown as errors/not errors in invocations. The "Errors" at the bottom left may be considered "crashes" or other internal failures of Cloud Functions separate from what your logic decides to return.

As @samthecodingman pointed out, while the screenshot may show what you observe, it's not enough for figuring out what the issue is. The type of the function, how it is used, where it's being called from, what languages it uses, what a client invoking the function sees and so on can help in clarifying this. It could be as simple as whether invocations of a HTTP Request Function return `HTTP 200 OK` or not.

In this case, the issue has been reported via the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203683939) and being reviewed by Google at this time.